# Wpf : How to make a letter pop out of the border

Tags: c#, wpf, border

how do make a letter pop out of the border?

[image]

I want to express it like this picture

I wrote a letter in the text on Border,
The letters are covered like in the picture.
Can you make this stick out like the picture below?

How can solve this?

[image]

this is my xaml code

```
<Window x:Class="TestProject.MainWindow"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:local="clr-namespace:TestProject"
    Width="800"
    Height="600"
    Title="ItemsControl 엘리먼트 : Template/ItemsPanel/ItemTemplate/ItemContainerStyle 속성 사용하기"
    FontFamily="나눔고딕코딩"
    FontSize="16">
    <Window.Resources>
        <local:TaskCollection x:Key="TaskCollectionKey" />
    </Window.Resources>
    <Grid>
        <ItemsControl
            HorizontalAlignment="Center"
            VerticalAlignment="Center"
            ItemsSource="{Binding Source={StaticResource TaskCollectionKey}}">
            <ItemsControl.Template>
                <ControlTemplate TargetType="ItemsControl">
                    <Border
                        BorderBrush="Black"
                        BorderThickness="3"
                        CornerRadius="15">
                        <ItemsPresenter />
                    </Border>
                </ControlTemplate>
            </ItemsControl.Template>
            <ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
                <ItemsPanelTemplate>
                    <WrapPanel />
                </ItemsPanelTemplate>
            </ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
            <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <DataTemplate.Resources>
                        <Style TargetType="TextBlock">
                            <Setter Property="HorizontalAlignment" Value="Center" />
                        </Style>
                    </DataTemplate.Resources>
                    <Grid>
                        <Ellipse
                            Stroke="Black"
                            StrokeThickness="3"
                            Fill="Gold" />
                        <StackPanel
                            HorizontalAlignment="Center"
                            VerticalAlignment="Center">
                            <TextBlock
                                Margin="5"
                                Text="{Binding Path=Priority}" />
                            <TextBlock
                                Margin="5"
                                Text="{Binding Path=TaskName}" />
                        </StackPanel>
                    </Grid>
                </DataTemplate>
            </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
            <ItemsControl.ItemContainerStyle>
                <Style>
                    <Setter Property="Control.Margin" Value="10"  />
                    <Setter Property="Control.Width"  Value="100" />
                    <Setter Property="Control.Height" Value="100" />
                    <Style.Triggers>
                        <Trigger
                            Property="Control.IsMouseOver" Value="True">
                                <Setter Property="Control.ToolTip"
                                    Value="{Binding RelativeSource={x:Static RelativeSource.Self},
                                        Path=Content.Description}" />
                        </Trigger>
                    </Style.Triggers>
                </Style>
            </ItemsControl.ItemContainerStyle>
        </ItemsControl>
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

Comment: Overflowing in WPF can sometimes be done by using negative margins, so that's the first thing I would try on the Taskname.

Comment: A canvas doesn't clip. You could use an eclipse instead of border and textblock inside a canvas

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you put the textblock in a canvas, that will not clip.

```
                    <StackPanel
                        HorizontalAlignment="Center"
                        VerticalAlignment="Center">
                        <TextBlock
                            Margin="5"
                            Text="{Binding Path=Priority}" />
                        <Canvas>
                        <TextBlock                                 
                            Text="{Binding Path=TaskName}" />
                        </Canvas>
                    </StackPanel>
```

[image]